# Desactivate webserver listening to a port in Quarkus Command Mode

Tags: quarkus

I'm using Quarkus in Command Mode to create a command line utility, but quarkus still launches a webserver and is listening on a port (indicated on startup).

I looked in documentation but didn't find a way to disable launching the webserver, am i missing something or could it be a feature ?

Answer (score 2):

I tried with the latest release `1.8.2.Final` with no web dependency. No web-server was spawned in this case.

```
2020-10-08 09:48:15,806 INFO  [io.quarkus] (Quarkus Main Thread) code-with-quarkus 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT on JVM (powered by Quarkus 1.8.2.Final) started in 0.899s. 
2020-10-08 09:48:15,808 INFO  [io.quarkus] (Quarkus Main Thread) Profile dev activated. Live Coding activated.
2020-10-08 09:48:15,808 INFO  [io.quarkus] (Quarkus Main Thread) Installed features: [cdi]
hello commando
2020-10-08 09:48:15,866 INFO  [io.quarkus] (Quarkus Main Thread) code-with-quarkus stopped in 0.044s
Quarkus application exited with code 0
```

Comment: thanks a lot ! it was because code.quarkus.io added the resteasy dependency and i missed that. thanks again !

Comment: I kind of remember rest-easy being a default dependency until recently.

Answer (score 1):

See [quarkus.http.host-enabled](https://quarkus.io/guides/all-config#quarkus-vertx-http_quarkus.http.host-enabled). However, if you disable HTTP, you’ll have to enable either HTTPS or listening on Unix domain sockets. So, if you do not need anything web-related, like a health endpoint, then you should remove any web dependency from your project, just like Haroon explained.

Comment: no i already tried that and it fail with following error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Must configure at least one of http, https or unix domain socket